# Serana following when I haven't told her to follow me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Serana from Dawnguard DLC is following me when I don't want her to.

I have a stealthy playing style so it's annoying when I constantly have her behind me.

**The setting looks like this**: She follows me automatically if I open her dialogue she says something about her brother and continues to follow me.

**When I press follow me she says**: I knew you'd miss me. But when I open her dialogue again it does the same thing.

I'd like to have her operate as the standard npcs with all the normal actions.

Any other npc from Dawnguard doesn't have this problem only Serana. I tried to  turn it off all but all mods I've found don't work!

Comment: Do you perhaps have an active quest that requires her to follow you? I know there are a couple of those.

Comment: @Timelord the problem seems similar; the "follow me" or the "wait here" option is not available. With a little alteration, the answer could provide a solution to both situations

Comment: @Timelord64 The answer explains that there's a long list of bugs tied to that character, including your issue

Comment: @Question Marks, your argument invalidates itself if you have to use the answer. We don't use answers as a basis for closing questions

Comment: @Timelord64 We don't, but I'm making the same point Ben brought up, the original question could be slightly modified to cover interaction with Serana not working, there's no need for two separate questions here.

Comment: @QuestionMarks, just dont use "the answer explains it" as an argument in future close votes.